# Looping elements in elixir based on JAVA

Tags: elixir

Good day, i have difficulties figuring out how to enumerate elements in elixir. So I have a `String List` of `elements` in Elixir. I have a function with the provided argument(`argument is element in the List`). I need to return an `element` from the `List` that is **next** to the element provided in argument.

**In java i would write something like this:**

```
    private mList ArrayList<> = new ArrayList(" "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h", "i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s",
"t","u","v","w","x","y","z" ")

    private String fun(String a) {
      for(int i = 0;i < mList.size;i++;) {
       if(mList.position(i) == a)
        return mList.position(i++) 
     }
    }
```

How can i achieve the same functionality in Elixir? I know how to enumerate a list but i don't understand how to return a element of position++ .

Comment: I don't know a lot of Java but shouldn't that be `mList.position(++i)` (or `i + 1`)?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to return an element from the List that is next to the element provided in argument.

There are many ways to do this. First, an idiomatic solution using pattern matching:

```
def first([a, b | _], a), do: b
def first([_, b | c], d), do: first([b | c], d)
def first([]), do: nil
```

This recursively checks if the first element matches the argument and if so returns the next one.

Here's a more direct translation of your algorithm:

```
def second(list, x) do
  case Enum.find_index(list, &(&1 == x)) do
    nil -> nil
    i -> Enum.at(list, i + 1)
  end
end
```

Test:

```
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

IO.inspect A.first(list, "d")
IO.inspect A.second(list, "d")
```

Output:

```
"e"
"e"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Sorry, i can't upvote your answer due to lack of reputation.

Comment: @KristjanTampere but you can mark the answer correct. Press the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [`Enum.drop_while/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#drop_while/2):

```rb
list =
  97..122
  |> Enum.to_list()
  |> List.to_string()
  |> String.split(~r//, trim: true)

case Enum.drop_while(list, & &1 != "d") do
  ["d", result | _] -> result
  _ -> nil
end
#⇒ "e"
```

---

or, even fancier, the sledgehammer of enums: [`Enum.reduce_while/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reduce_while/3):

```rb
Enum.reduce_while(list, false, fn
  x, false -> {:cont, x == "d"}
  x, true -> {:halt, x}
  _, _ -> {:cont, false}
end)
#⇒ "e"
```